# Pulling URL's address from a string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm a bit new to the sed/bash, I'm trying to pull url's from this address (basically the .com's/.infos/xyz) Basically grab the domains in the "" and output into a new file.

**Source:**

```
(window,arguments);})(2,340000,625803,"domain.com",7,3,0,1200,"anotherdomain.info",0,[],1,[],[],false,"sdfs-fdsf",0 "remove_file_ext":true,"mode":"sector","sector":".dlitre"},"domain.xyz",5,0.4,0.8,[],0,"//vghvghv.
```

**Desired output:**

```
domain.com
anotherdomain.info
domain.xyz
```

Comment: Post any efforts you already tried. We could help you with that

Comment: What about your previous questions? You have not accepted or provided feedback on them and here you are asking a new one. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Inian, I was about to write the same comment, thanks for pointing. Bridget, we all are here to learn here, please do add what did you learn from your previous answer as your previous answer was neither accepted nor any response or up-vote from your side too?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @BridgetRoe, sure. just start learning as we all do here and always good to share what you have tried, posting my answer now which I didn't post since Inian asked you question.

Comment: @BridgetRoe, also try to give feedback to people for their answers + try to encourage them (by up-vote if you think someone has put effort) then finally try to mark an answer as correct so that many others could get benefit from this post too seeing your remarks as an OP, cheers and happy learning :)

Comment: What's your criteria for identifying the target strings? Is it based on their location on each line (after some string, some number of characters in, some number of comma-separated fields in, or something else) or based on some regexp they satisfy (e.g. all alphanumeric with one `.` or something else) or something else? Do you ONLY want domain names that end in .com's/.infos/xyz or are those just examples and you want all domain names suffixes including .net, .biz, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{while(match($0,/"[^"]*/)){val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1);if(val ~ /com|info|xyz/){print val};$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}}' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/"[^"]*/)){
     val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1);
     if(val ~ /com|info|xyz/){ print val };
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: I think regex could be improved like this" `\.(com|info|xyz)$` so that it would guarantee fields ending in `com|info|xyz`